# Capistrano deploy fails on rake assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

When executing `cap production deploy` I get the error:

```
[25307399] Command: RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Command::Failed: RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile stdout: Nothing   written
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile stderr: rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- sass/script/node
/Users/me/rails/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support    /dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
```

Checking similar questions got me to try and debug by running `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` on my local machine and it fails with the same error:

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- sass/script/node
/Users/evan/rails/do-indie/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support  /dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
```

There are hints that it's an issue with the `sass` gem, so I uninstalled all my sass gems and reinstalled them. Same error. Then I did some more digging and saw this might be an issue with sass 3.3.0, so I installed v 3.2.13 but I'm still getting the `cannot load such file -- sass/script/node` and not sure how to keep trouble shooting this.

Comment: This may have to do more with what you want and don't want installed on production.  My Cap recipes actually compile the assets on the Dev box and push them over, because I didn't want to install libv8 or node on the production box.

Comment: From the current directory, look in sass/script dir and see if a file node is there.

Comment: cheers, I seem to have gotten this fixed by adding ```gem 'sass'
gem 'compass', '0.12.2'``` to my gemfile and creating a new rvm gemset. Just curious, do you have any recommended reading for capistrano? I have moved on from this error to a new one re: unicorn and am finding the whole deploy process incredibly frustrating.

Comment: Capistrano is a beast all of it's own. I find the documentation light, but it's very intuitive.  I have some examples I can share; but mostly, I pick them up in gists, etc. I'll post as I can.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jancel/9893965 Check out this, I have my Gemfile and my deploy.rb with some examples of running remote rake commands and more.  This also supports 0 downtime deploys for code changes.